# Exception: Input blob arguments do not match net inputs

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

This question has been asked before but with different context. So please dont mark it as duplicate.
I want to feedforward a network step by step. First feedforward upto some layer then get its result change it and then pass it on to the next layer. Here is the code.

```
forward_kwargs = {'data': blobs['data'].astype(np.float32, copy=False)}
blobs_out = net.forward(end='proposal',**forward_kwargs)
forward_kwargs = {'proposal': blobs_out}
blobs_out = net.forward(start='roi_pool_conv5',**forward_kwargs)
```

When it run this code, it gives error

> Exception: Input blob arguments do not match net inputs.

this error comes from the file `pycaffe.py`. The line in this file giving error is

```
 if set(kwargs.keys()) != set(self.inputs):
            raise Exception('Input blob arguments do not match net inputs.')
```

Because in prototxt file i have mentioned only two inputs `data` and `im_info`. But i want to input my network again from `roi_pool_conv5` layer and when i send this argument as start layer to network it checks whether this blob is in the inputs or not. Clearly it is not in the inputs. I cannot mention this in input because i am unsure of dimension. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you don't know dimensions of `proposal`.
If so, you just fill dummy dimensions in prototxt file and reshape it before you forward.
After running your program, batch size is gonna fixed, right?
Then you can reshape your `roi_pool_conv5` layer and your network!
I hope this answer is helpful to you :)